# TypeError while trying to add Label widgets in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to add some labels from the list to Tkinter GUI:

```
x = 10
y = 10
i = 0
Labels = ['Name', 'RName', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Cast', 'Add', 'Mob No.', 'Adhar No.']   
for Label in Labels:
    lbp1n = Label(window, text=str(Label))
    lbp1n.place(x=x, y=x)
    x += 10
```

And I'm getting this exception:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: ask yourself this question, what is `Label` on line six of your code.

Comment: By the way, it is not necessary to convert labels to `str` in the loop, because the `Labels` list contains the strings only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label is build-in method, I replaced it by some_label.

```
x=10
y=10
i=0
Labels=['Name','RName','Gender','Age','Cast','Add','Mob No.','Adhar No.']   
for some_label in Labels:
    lbp1n = Label(window, text=str(some_label))
    lbp1n.place(x=x,y=x)
    x+=10
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the for {declare anything other than Label} in Lables because your overlapping tkinter method name as variable